# Use multiple Range in DataValidation

Tags: google-sheets

I hope my question won't be confusing, if you have any doubt about what I asked don't hesitate to tell me, please!

I want to use two separated range for a drop-down list but I really don't know how to do this. I even tried to ask a cell to print the two ranges but I don't find any formula to do that ><.

In my example, I have two range: "namesNinjaSkills" and "namesNinjaMasterSkills" who are two columns with the wanted skills. I want to have a dropdown at a certain level which proposes the two type of skills. Do I have to manually put them one below another (it would be really painful ><)?

I've seen that the data validation doesn't want to take more than one range, so I tried to say to cell A307 "you are all "namesNinjaSkills" and then all "namesNinjaMasterSkills"" but I cannot found a formula for that, I can absolutely make this with one range, but not with two.

Maybe it's a stupid question, I'm sorry if it's the case ^^

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you need (?)

## EXAMPLE 1:

[image]

### Sheet1:

**D20: Data Validation > List of items: `I made a choice,I didn't make a choice`**

**F20: Data Validation > List from a range: `Sheet2!D8:D11`**

### Sheet2:

**D8: `=IF(Sheet1!D20 = B6; QUERY(B8:B11;;-1);IF(Sheet1!D20 = C6; QUERY(C8:C11;;-1);))`**

---

## EXAMPLE 2:

**formula in D2:**

```
=IF(A2=F2, {H3:H},
 IF(A2=F3, {I3:I},
 IF(A2=F4, {J3:J}, )))
```

[image]

**data validation in A2:**

> [image]

**data validation in B2:**

> [image]

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18JTMmtgUck4J5Fm0wiuCN_TUIDA8pzmET4pvswYawc4/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: Thanks ! The first example may probably help me :D !

Comment: I know but I'm still looking for a solution that don't need to rewrite the list for every different dropdown ^^' I don't even know if that's possible x')